# Extending a template class while fixing the template parameter

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I have defined a class

```
template <class T> class NodeMap {

NodeMap(int n, T defaultEntry = NULL);

virtual ~NodeMap();

T& operator[](const node& u);

...

}
```

which maps an object of type `node` to an object of parameter type `T`.

Now I'd like to have a class `Matching`, which is essentially a `NodeMap<node>`. For convenience, I'd like to add methods like `isProperMatching(Graph& G)` and `match(node u, node v)`. Can `Matching` inherit from `NodeMap<node>`? Is it possible (and if yes, is it a good idea) to extend a template class with a fixed template parameter?

Comment: This is fine. `NodeMap<node>` is a perfectly normal class, just with a slightly odd spelling of its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following possibilities as far at the code you've shown tells me what you are doing:

1. Specialize `Nodemap` for `T=node`, to include the additional methods you want to have. For convenience you can then typedef `Nodemap<node>` to `Matching`. However this might add some code duplication of the Methods you have in the nonspecialized template.
2. Derive from `Nodemap<node>` as you suggested. This is a valid approach, if you design `Nodemap` in a way that makes it a proper base class. The virtual destructor suggests you did that already, although it might not be necessary to make methods virtual at all.
3. If possible, provide the additional functionality as free functions, so there is no need to derive from or specialize `Nodemap<node>`

I would consider a mixed approach of the first two: Make a base class template (I'll call it `NodeMapBase`) that contains the common functionality of `NodeMap`s and `Matching`, then derive the `NodeMap` template from the corresponding base class template (probably without adding much functionality) and derive `Matching` from `NodeMapBase<node>`. If you have a look at MSVC's standard library implementation you see that a lot there.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having a common base class `NodeMapBase`? Currently, I see a `Matching` as a `NodeMap<node>` with added functionality, so the benefit of introducing another base class is not clear to me.

Comment: If you see no benefit, simply don't use it. Sometimes it's a viable option, e.g. if a `Matching` needs a base class constructor that a `NodeMap` does not provide - then you can provide that constructor in your base class. In such cases, the inheritance is a pure technical way to avoid code duplication, not to express a real "is-a" relation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's commonly used.

```
class Matching : public NodeMap<node> {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how the interface of `Matching` should look like. If you want to provide exactly the same methods plus some convenience methods, you can inherit it

```
class Matching : public NodeMap<node> {...};
```

But if `Matching` is not a `NodeMap<node>`, i.e. provides a different interface, you should only use it as an aggregate

```
class Matching {
private:
    NodeMap<node> matchingNodes;
public:
    // public interface of Matching
    bool isProperMatching(Graph& G);
    bool match(node u, node v);
    ...
};
```

BTW, this advice is independant of `NodeMap` being a template or not.